# python regex pattern to check if string contatins any characters other than specified

Tags: python, regex

As the title says - I need to return `True` if the specified string contains any characters other than `'a'`, `'b'` and `'c'`.
I've tried

```
 r'[^(abc)]'
```

but it doesn't work for me. I can't figure out how to make a negation of pattern.

Comment: Just `re.search('[^abc]', s)`.

Comment: The problem was that i've inserted the check in the wrong part of the code. I have actually specified the correct pattern in the question. Still thanks for help and quick answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead assertion like below.

```
>>> st = "foo"
>>> if re.match(r'^(?!.*[abc])', st):
        print('True')
    else:
        print('false')


True
```

`^(?!.*[abc])` forces the regex engine to match the start of a string only if the string contains any but not of `a` or `b` or `c`

Answer (score 0):

```
^[^abc]+$
```

Try this.This returns a string `True` if it has no `a or b or c`.
Use `re.match()`.